# how can I upload csv file in wordpress 4.9.9 upwards

Tags: csv, upload

recent security changes have made my csv upload not work saying that the type is invalid.  I need to bypass this change but have failed to do by adding the mime type to the relevant filters.

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['csv'] = 'text/csv'; //Adding csv extension

    return $mime_types;
}

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug -- or security "feature" depending whom you ask -- in WordPress 4.9.9 and 5.0.1 core.

The quick fix -- add this to wp-config.php

```
define(‘ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS’, true);
```

This will open potential security risks by stopping the "newly enhanced" WordPress file type checking, but not more of a risk thank WP 4.9.8 or 5.0 came with.

Remember to turn this to false if WordPress fixes the CSV bug.

You can read more details and follow related threads in [this article](https://www.storelocatorplus.com/wordpress-4-9-9-file-type-not-permitted-workaround/) for my user base.

You may also try adding this to theme or plugin code but it fundamentally changes the way the mime type system works in WordPress.   Fixes the issue but you may have more long term problems if you keep this in place:

```
function fix_wp_csv_mime_bug( $data, $file, $filename, $mimes ) {
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );
            $ext = $wp_filetype['ext'];
            $type = $wp_filetype['type'];
            $proper_filename = $data['proper_filename'];

            return compact( 'ext', 'type', 'proper_filename' );
}
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'fix_wp_csv_mime_bug', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: WordPress Core has been updated to patch this bug in the WordPress 5.X line only via WordPress 5.0.3

As of January 2019 there is no patch to the 4.9 or earlier releases that includes this patch.

The patch came out in January 2019.  

You can look at version updates for the full Major.Minor releases of WordPress here: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions

Maybe they will back-port this patch to those not wanting to use 5.x